# writing a sum as a complex integral

Tags: summation, complex-integration

I would like to write the sum over a series as a complex integral using residual theorem. I don't know if it is possible or not but I tried something and I don't know if I wrote something true...

Given the series $\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty}{e^{-n\nu}}$ how can someone write it as a complex integral? I know it looks seely because everyone knows what the sum equals to but I have reasons to write it that way.

Using the function $\pi coth(\pi z)$ one can sample all the points in the sum, but it's not just from 1 to $\infty$, so by adding heaviside function: $\theta(z+z^*)$ we can sample just the upper plane.

Now, naivly I can say that $\sum_{n=1} ^{\infty}{e^{-n\nu}}= \sum{Res(\pi coth(\pi z) \theta(z+z*)e^{-\nu z},z=z_{poles})}$

$= \sum_{poles} \int \frac{1}{2\pi i} \pi coth(\pi z) \theta(z+z*)e^{-\nu z} dz$ with a half circle contour.
But I have two problems, first- the theorem is for a final number of poles and what I wrote has infinit number of poles, and I'm not sure if it's legit to add the heaviside...

Maybe someone has a different approach? maybe it's not possible?

Thank you

Comment: But $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1} ^{\infty}{e^{-n\nu}} = \frac {e^{-\nu}} {1-e^{-\nu}} = \frac 1 {e^{\nu} - 1}$

Comment: that i know but still I want to write this as a complex integral... looks seely but I have reasons for writing it in that way.

Comment: $\displaystyle \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\nu} \frac 1 {e^\nu - 1} = \frac {-e^\nu} {(e^\nu - 1)^2}$

Comment: "I have reasons for writing it in that way" then this is borderline [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: should I delete this question then?

Comment: No, you should clarify what you want.